# Does it affect the existing application on appStore if we change Twitter application Default Access type?

Tags: iphone, twitter

Hi 
I created the new application in Twitter & enabled xOuth support for the same.
Previously the application Default Access type was "read only". U sing the consumer key & secret I made my iphone application & it is now on app store.

Now i want to change Default Access type to "read-write" mode, as read only application cannot use "POST" method. 
[i.e. while using method "statuses/update" to post new tweet i am getting response as :

error : Read-only application cannot POST

So I want to change "Default Access type" to "read-write".

My question is that if i perform above change will it affect my current app users ? As i afraid that doing so will change my consumer key & secret (May be) (using which i created app & used for app store.) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a Twitter application from "read only" to "read and write" will not effect your existing users. They will have to authorized again to upgrade the applications access to their account to read and write however.